# if statement issue with mysql getstring

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement

I have an issue with the if/else function in my Java code (Android / Eclipse).

When I'm in debug mode, checkGender is equal to "M", but goes directly to "else" instruction and considers that 'checkGender' is not equal to "M". I don't understand why? For information, searcher.getString("Gender") takes information from MySQL.

```
String checkGender = "";

checkGender = searcher.getString("Gender");

if(checkGender == "M")
{
    bGenderM.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
    bGenderF.setChecked(true);
}
```

Debug info :
checkGender = "M" (id=8300460...)
value[0] = M

If I replace "searcher.getString("Gender");" by a simple "M", it works.

Thanks for your help.

Tom

Answer (score 2):

Actually best would be to do it **"Yoda-style"**

```
if("M".equals(checkGender)) {
     //code for male
} else {
     //code for female
}
```

That way you avoid potential `NullPointerException` for the case that `checkGender == null`

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method instead of `==` for `String` comparison.

```
if(checkGender.equals("M")) {

    bGenderM.setChecked(true);

} else {

    bGenderF.setChecked(true);

}
```

OR, use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method and it better...

```
if(checkGender.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {

    bGenderM.setChecked(true);

} else {

    bGenderF.setChecked(true);

}
```